# Infinitesimal increments to independent variables in orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, orthogonal-matrices

I'm trying to read the proof for existence of the Singular Value Decomposition from the [Eckart-Young (1936) paper](http://k7moa.com/pdf/Eckart_and_Young_1936.pdf).

In page 215, the authors mention "if $u$ is any orthogonal matrix
and the independent variables that determine it are given any infinitesimal increments, the resulting increment of $u$ is,
$$\delta u = u s$$

where $s$ a skew-symmetric matrix whose elements are infinitesimal,
but otherwise arbitrary."

I'm unable to understand this statement and find the reference mentioned in the paper. The closest explanation I've been able to determine is from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Lie_algebra) which is still confusing to me.

Is there a simpler explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

I had looked at this paper a few years back, and here's the interpretation of the proof that I have in my notes.  Perhaps this will help.

We begin with a lemma:

> **Lemma:** There exist orthogonal matrices $U,V$ such that both $UAV^T$ and $UBV^T$ are diagonal if and only if $AB^T$ and $B^TA$ are both symmetric.

**Proof of Lemma:** $\implies$ is straightforward.

For $\Longleftarrow$, it helps to note that if $AB^T$ and $B^TA$ are symmetric, then the symmetric block-matrices
$$
\hat A = \pmatrix{0&A\\A^T&0}, \quad 
\hat B = \pmatrix{0&B\\B^T&0}
$$
commute.  We can then use an orthogonal matrix that simultaneously diagonalizes $\hat A$ and $\hat B$ to construct the required $U$ and $V$.

Now, let $\tilde B$ be the minimizer, i.e. suppose that $\tilde B$ is the $B$ that minimizes $\|A - B\|$.  Let $\tilde B = \tilde U \tilde \Sigma \tilde V^T$ be its singular value decomposition.  Consider any skew symmetric matrix $S$ (i.e. $S^T = -S$).  Let $U:[-1,1] \to O(m)$ be such that $U(0) = \tilde U$ and $U'(0) = S \tilde U$.  Denote $B(t) = U(t) \tilde \Sigma \tilde V$.

Because $\tilde B$ is a minimizer, we should find that 
\begin{align*}
0 & = \left.
    \frac{d}{dt}\|A - B(t)\|^2
\right|_{t = 0} 
= 
\left.
    \frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{tr}[(A - B(t))^T(A - B(t))]
\right|_{t = 0}
\\ & =
-2\operatorname{tr}(A^T U'(0) \Sigma V^T) = 
-\operatorname{tr}(A^T S\tilde B) = - \operatorname{tr}([\tilde BA^T]S)
\end{align*}
Thus, $\tilde BA^T$ is in the orthogonal complement of the skew symmetric matrices, so it is symmetric.

By a similar argument (using instead a $V(t)$), we find that $\tilde B^TA$ must be symmetric.  So, we may apply the lemma to find $U$ and $V$ such that both $UAV^T$ and $U\tilde BV^T$ are diagonal.

Having reduced to this case, we find that the nearest diagonal matrix $\tilde \Sigma$ of rank $r$ to the diagonal matrix $\Sigma = U^TAV$ is clearly found by setting $\tilde \Sigma_{ii} = \Sigma_{ii}$ for $1 \leq i \leq r$, which is precisely the desired result. $\square$

---

A proof via Weyl's inequalities:

> **Lemma:** For $m \times n$ matrices $X,Y$ any $1 \leq i,j \leq n$, we have
>   $$
> \sigma_{i+j - 1}(X + Y) \leq \sigma_i(X) + \sigma_j(Y)
> $$

Setting $X = A-B, Y = B, j = r+1$, we find that
$$
\sigma_{i+r}(A) \leq \sigma _{i}(A - B) + \sigma_{r+1}(B)
$$
However, since $B$ has rank $r$, we may state that $\sigma_{r+1}(B) = 0$, so that $\sigma_{i}(A - B) \geq \sigma_{i+r}(A)$.  Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
\|A - B\|^2 &= 
\sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2(A - B) \geq 
\sum_{i=1}^{n-r} \sigma_i^2(A - B)
\\ & \geq \sum_{i=r+1}^{n} \sigma_i^2(A)
\end{align*}

And equality is attained when we set $B = \tilde B$.  Thus, $\tilde B$ is indeed a minimizer. $\square$

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the parameter $t$ in $U(t)$ is. How're we able to show that such a $U(t)$ exists?

Comment: $t$ is just a real parameter. One way to show that sub a $U$ exists is to exhibit an example. You can verify that the function $$U(t)= e^{tS} \tilde U$$ is such an example (where $e^M$ denotes the matrix exponential).

Comment: Thanks that helps! This style of proof is pretty different to the ones I've seen before. So is $B(t)$ is a low-rank matrix whose singular vectors are being rotated around to find the appropriate subspace?

Comment: @SrinivasEswar that is certainly one way to think about it.  If you like, the first $B(t)$ (where $U$ varies with $t$) involves a rotation in the codomain whereas the second $B(t)$ (where $V$ varies with $t$) involves a rotation in the domain.  That is, if $A$ is $m \times n$, then the first $B(t)$ involves rotations in $\Bbb R^m$ and the second involves rotations in $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: So, is this $U(t)$ what they're mentioning for $\delta u$ in the paper? Can this parameterisation be extended to all orthogonal matrices only or any matrix in general?

Comment: The paper in the argument is roughly this: "If $u$ is such that the distance $x$ is minimized, then we must have $\delta \,x^2 = 0$.  Since $\delta\, x^2 = -(\alpha \beta',s)$ where $s$ is an arbitrary skew-symmetric matrix, $\alpha \beta'$ must be symmetric".  The point of introducing the parameter $t$ is to avoid using the language of infinitessimals (i.e. all the $\delta$'s).  I don't know what you mean by extending the parameterization.

Comment: Another perspective: $U(t)$ is a differentiable path through the manifold of unitary matrices that passes through $\tilde U$ at $t=0$.  By considering many different paths $U(t)$ and using the fact that $\|A - B(t)\|^2$ ($x^2$ in the language of the paper) is necessarily minimal at $t = 0$, we come to the conclusion that $\tilde BA^T$ must be symmetric.

Comment: I am asking about the statement that $U(0) = \hat{U}$ and $U'(0) = S\hat{U}$. Here $U(0)$ being an orthogonal matrix seems to be only due to it coming from the SVD of $B(t)$. Can this same parametrisation, say $Z:[-1,1] \to O(m)$ be done for some arbitrary matrix $Z$. It seems to work for the matrix exponential example you've provided.

Comment: I suppose you mean an arbitrary *orthogonal* matrix $Z$, otherwise we wouldn't have a map to $O(m)$.  If that's what you mean then the answer is yes, we can find such a map satisfying $Z(0) = Z$, whatever $Z$ happens to be.  The trick here is ensuring that $Z(t)$ is orthogonal for **all** $t \in [-1,1]$.  As it turns out, for any differentiable map $Z:[-1,1] \to O(m)$, $Z'(0)$ will be skew-symmetric.  So if you meant to have $U'(0) = Z$, then that can only happen if $Z$ is skew-symmetric.

Comment: I think this is the heart of the question in my post. Can we show that $Z'(0)$ is always skew-symmetric?

Comment: I see. Yes, we can show that $Z’(0)$ will necessarily be $S\tilde U$ with $S$ skew-symmetric. This fact is a consequence of the fact that the skew-symmetric matrices form the Lie Algebra corresponding to the Lie Group of orthogonal matrices. Giving the full context or a proof for this is a bit beyond the scope of a comment or quick edit, but perhaps you can post another question. If you’re looking for a text I recommend Brian C Hall’s book on Matrix Lie Groups and Lie Algebras.

Answer (score 1):

> Here's one way I was able to show that statement for mappings of the form mentioned in Omnomnomnom's answer.

Consider,

\begin{align}
&U:[-1,1]\rightarrow O(m) \\ 
&U(0) = \tilde{U}
\end{align}

We want to show that $U'(0) = \tilde{U}S$ where $S$ is an arbitrary skew-symmetric matrix.

Since $U(t)$ is an orthogonal matrix we have,

$$U(t)^TU(t) = I_m$$
Differentiating with respect to $t$,
$$U'(t)^TU(t) + U(t)^TU'(t) = 0$$
This shows us that $S = U(t)^TU'(t)$ is skew-symmetric (since $S^T + S = 0$).
Evaluating at $t=0$,
\begin{align}
\tilde{U}^TU'(0) = S \\
\implies U'(0) = \tilde{U}S
\end{align}